# How to get text value from string ArrayAdapter in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I have an app with two activities: 1st - listview with links to html files, second is a webview.
For example I press "First Topic" in the listview, it opens "1.html" in the webview. I want to get text value of clicked element in the listview and show it in textview of second activity by this method:

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
title.setText(getString(R.string.app_name));
```

Here is a code of ListViewActivity:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private ListView lv1;
    private String lv_arr[] = { "First Topic", "Second Topic" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);


        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items,
                lv_arr));
        lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                String itemname = new Integer(position).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(ListViewActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("defStrID", itemname);
                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I pass the value which was clicked in listview to webviewactivity? Help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the line

```
String itemname = new Integer(position).toString();
```

to this

```
String itemname = lv_arr[position];
```

Comment: But how can I put it in the next activity in `TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
title.setText(what should I write here?);`

Comment: @Sabre: aren't you able to put it into intent extra? if you can,then you should be able to get it in next activity.

Comment: Bundle b = new Bundle(); title.setText(b.getString("defStrID").toString);

Comment: I can't change this line `String itemname = new Integer(position).toString();` because it passes position of file to open it. I think I should do something like this in onItemClick `String pressed = lv_arr[position]; Bundle c = new Bundle(); b.putString("pagename", pressed); intent.putExtras(c);`

Comment: in your next activity, get it like this `title.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("defStrID"));`

Comment: its all up to you, for how and which values you push into bundle and retrieve it later :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `itemname` declaration to this.

```
String itemname = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name)).getText().toString();
```